# How do I force \section's to start on a new page if they don't fit on current page?

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, memoir

So I am writing a programming book, and I use `\section` for each topic. For example, I'd write,

```
\section{Another way to double-space a file}

\begin{lstlisting}
awk 'BEGIN { ORS="\n\n" }; 1'
\end{lstlisting}

BEGIN is a special kind of pattern which ...

\section{Triple-space a file}

....
```

Sometimes I get a situation where the title of the section is at the very bottom of the page, and the example is at the beginning of a new page, etc.

Does anyone know how can I force `\section`s to be on a new page if all of it doesn't fit in the current page?

I am using `memoir` document class, btw.

Comment: Did you try using `\pagebreak`?

Comment: TeX has the `\penality` primitive to control where page breaks are encouraged. The `\section` definition should use this to discourage page breaks right after it. You can try a `\goodbreak` before `\section` or `\raggedbottom` in the preamble.

Comment: @Christian: Indeed `\section` tries to avoid creating orphans, but apparently inserting `lstlisting` without any preceding text breaks this.

Comment: The empty line between `\section` and `lstlisting` is a paragraph break. IIRC, this breaks the `\section` orphan behaviour.

Answer (score 28):

My suggestion is to focus on getting the content and structure of your document in place before attending to details such as this. The reason is that the layout of your document will shift constantly while content is still being added. Because of this, the most efficient use of time is to focus on writing and ignore these details until the rough draft is done.

Once the rough draft is ready, then you can clean these bad section breaks up by inserting `\goodbreak`, `\newpage`, etc. as part of the editing process.

Comment: I honestly don't agree. I get motivated by seeing my text in near final form during the writing process. If it looks ugly I tend to get less motivated.

Comment: It's worth debunking the classic myth that LaTeX is "more efficient":  https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0115069.    
I'm still happy to settle for "more beautiful"

Answer (score 17):

Have a look at the `\Needspace` command. Put it before the `\section` command and the section will not start unless there is enough space left on the page.

for example:

```
\Needspace{5\baselineskip}
\section{Another way to double-space a file}

\begin{lstlisting}
awk 'BEGIN { ORS="\n\n" }; 1'
\end{lstlisting}

BEGIN is a special kind of pattern which ...

\section{Triple-space a file}

....
```

To start the section on the next page unless there are att least 5 '\baselineskip' of space available. Be sure to include `\usepackage{needspace}` if you are not using `memoir` before the `\begin{document}` line.

Answer (score 6):

Starting a `lstlisting` environment immediately after a section title triggers a bug of listings. It can be solved by

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\preto\lstlisting{\@nobreakfalse}
\makeatother
```

In this case, in order to avoid adding undesired vertical space, call `lstlisting` as

```
\begin{lstlisting}[aboveskip=0pt]
```

Probably this won't solve your problem completely, as a page break may happen after the `lstlisting` and I don't know how to avoid it. :(

Answer (score 4):

`\raggedbottomsectiontrue` often helps (but not always for some reason)