# Section should automatically start new page if the whole section does not fit on current page

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, titlesec, sections-paragraphs

I would like my sections to start on a new page if they do not fit on the current page. In other words:  if a section fits on the current page print it, if it does not fit start printing it on the next page.

I would like this to be done **automatically**.

`\usepackage{titlesec}` seems to be the solution, but I can not get it to do the job.

- Should it be done with `titlesec`? how ?
- Is there a better approach?

Comment: [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16993/13296) is very similar but does not give automatic solutions

Comment: The *whole* section?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question right, but yes (my sections are quite short (longest are 3 pages long))

Comment: So your question is very unclear: three pages *can't* fit on a page, can they?

Comment: Right, we should find a way to formulate it better, the idea is : if a section would be cut it, starts on a new page.

Comment: Do you mean:

If the next section can fit on the current page, just print it as-is. Otherwise, put in a page break and start the section on the new page.

?

Comment: @MikeRenfro exactly

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51433/5763

Comment: I think a manual editing is easier ;-)

Comment: @Marco wrong :-)

Comment: @FrankMittelbach: I am happy to be wrong ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a simple solution that does require only a single pass ...

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\mysection{\vfil\penalty-9999\vfilneg\section}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\mysection{A} \lipsum[3]
\mysection{B} \lipsum[1-2]
\mysection{C} \lipsum[5] 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

1. Set `\label`s at the start and end of the section and check if they are on the same page. You'll need multiple runs and you have to mark the end of sections.
2. Typeset the content of the section e.g. in a minipage and check its length. This will be quite fragile. And you will have to catch the content.

Comment: I am not very familiar with Latex macros. How would I check if both `\labels` are on the same page and insert a `\newpage` at the first label if they are not? *don't hesitate sending me to some documentation*

Comment: *multiple runs* in item 1 might be a slight understatement :-) Inserting a page break will make everything behind it move to new places, so <number of pages> might well be a good estimate for <number of runs>. In particular, once a page break is inserted, it doesn't make sense to look at the following labels at all.

Comment: @StephanLehmke: I know. And I know that this is probably a lot easier in DocScape than in LaTeX. `:-)`

Comment: why should that be easier in DocScape? you have to analyse the page situation in both cases but that particular scenario can in fact be simply modeled by glue and penalties in one go. Alternative is to invoke your own OR and store the accumulated page fragment away and recombine later (that is what multicols does basically with the material in front).

Comment: @FrankMittelbach I think what Martin refers to is that DocScape, being a data-based system, has a slightly different input model than (La)TeX. While the input of LaTeX is basically a stream with very limited lookahead capabilities, DocScape is operating on a document-structured tree and can thus easily look at the complete content of the next section, chapter or whatever. That there is a simple penalty-based solution in this case was not known at the time Martin's comment was written ;-) But there are a lot of situations in advanced layout composition where this is not the case.

Comment: @Stephan I understand the difference that you outline, but this doesn't really help if you have formatting dependencies on formatting of components unless those dependencies are strictly linear or strictly local. But if that is the case then you can (with some adjustments) use something like an aux file as a simple form of database.

Comment: @Stephan btw I wouldn't call it a "simple" penalty-based solution but an "elegant one ... only that I can't really take creadit for it. It is due to Plass/Knuth from "Breaking paragraphs into lines" or some other paper on the penalty/glue/box algebra as they called it. Might even be recorded in the TeXbook in some shape or form in appendix D(irty tricks).

Comment: @FrankMittelbach If you mean using the aux file for "stabilizing" a complex layout in multiple runs, then this will get extremely tedious when the changes effected in the next run influence page breaking, as this will invalidate all subsequent layout decisions. All the successful examples of this are really annotations to otherwise unchanging pages like todo notes. I had a lengthy discussion on this with Manuel Montero Pineda on an analogous subject (FO layout optimization with multiple passes) and he aknowledged the things possible in DocScape are next to impossible to achieve with FO.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Elegant indeed. I didn't mean "simple" in a derogative sense. Btw. "simple" is your own wording :-) It's extremely impressive this question can be resolved that way. But as long as you're considering one page break at a time, penalties will only take you so far...

Answer (score 0):

If the sections will never be longer than one page, you could wrap them in some unbreakable environment (e.g. minipage) and they will automatically be moved to the next page if they don't fit.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\section{title}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{minipage}

\bigskip
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\section{title}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}

\bigskip
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\section{title}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{minipage}

\bigskip
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\section{title}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```