# Insert image if there is room in the current column

Tags: graphics, layout

I use this: [Section should automatically start new page if the whole section does not fit on current page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50783/section-should-automatically-start-new-page-if-the-whole-section-does-not-fit-on) to make sure sections start on a new page (or in this case column) if they don't fit the remainder of the column.

Is it possible to detect when there is more than x cm left in the bottom of a column and insert an image there to fill out the space?

Comment: if this mean, if there is not enough space, you will omit this image? or you allow it to float to the top of the next column (what do `figure` or `table`  placement option  `htb`)?

Comment: @Zarko, I think he means something like this: `paragraph A <code of the image> paragraph B`. After paragraph A, we check if there is enough vertical space in the current column. If the condition is satisfied, we insert the image. If not, we just let it float to the next page. If the user is writing a paper, it is better to let the page float, but if he is writing something like a manual or tutorial, it is usually better to let the image be as close as possible to the text.

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh, that is exactly what placement specifier  `[htb]` do.  OP should look https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh That's exaclty what i'm looking for!

I'm making a printable D&D spell book, and the images are just there to fill out the empty room, so it doesn't really matter which page they appear on. Is there any way of making the images fill out all the remaining space so i don't get multiple images after each other?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425892/place-figure-at-bottom-of-this-page-or-the-top-of-the-next-page?r=SearchResults&s=1|50.5604  You can still use a float without a caption.